# z-index to always display icons

Tags: html, css, z-index

I am trying to get two font-awesome icons to always display over a series of divs.

When the user hovers over the main details, I can get the details to be surrounded by a border with a different background. However, this does prevent the the icons from being displayed correctly.

I understand that this requires the use of the [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp), but all of my attempts to display the icons correctly have failed. I have searched SO & Google, but still cannot solve this simple issue.

This is what I am attempting to achieve:

[image]

This is what I currently have:

[image]

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6233114/bf2h7voz/) example.

I would really appreciate some assistance solving this issue.

Just some code to display the jsfiddle:

```
<div id="id_membership_details_resume_template" class="live_preview_wrapper noselect resumeStyleWrapper10" dir="ltr" style="direction: ltr;">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this

```
#id_resume_detail_content {
    position: relative;
}
```

Edit: and update this also for the X button ( just changed top and right according to jsfiddle provided template )

```
.resume_details_unselect {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 45px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works. I would never have seen that error. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem buddy, glad it helped.